# How to update data from html table to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, html-table

I have 4 columns in sqltable.
How can I update solution cell value to SQL table. Need to update value based on checkbox value as userid.

```
   <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_query`);
   ?>
  <table id="t01" >
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>User Id</th>
         <th>Query</th>
         <th>Solution</th>
         <th>Date</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
       <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
       ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></td>
          <td><?php eco $row['userquery']; ?></td>
          <td contenteditable='true'><?php echo $row['solution']; ?></td>
          <td><?php $row['querydate']; ?></td>
          <td style='display:none;'><input type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $row['userid'];?>' name='check_list[]' value='<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>' checked /></td>                       
       </tr>
       <?php
             }
       ?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You're not closing the `"` on the second line for the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should not use `mysql`anymore since its deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.
second, you are using double-quote at the beginning and single-quote at the end of your query.
and third: you forgot the singlequot in the `[]`, thats not how you access an item from the array, you need `$row['userid']`